# Получение первого ключа двумерного массива.

Tags: массивы, php

Как получить первый ключ массива, если нам известен второй?

Например:

```
$ar[2][3]=4;
```

От сюда нам известно только 3, нужно получить 2-ку. Спасибо.

Comment: А если индекс 3 будет в нескольких элементах массива?
Т.е.:

`$ar[2][3] = 4;
$ar[8][3] = 15;`

Comment: Что-то ничего не понял. В смысле неизвестно какой ключ перед 3-м? А надо получить его значение?

Comment: @DemoS да именно, нужно значение первого ключа.

@Dem нет такого не бывает в моем массиве, все ключи второго уровня уникальные... повторяться могу только первые.

Т.е:

    $ar[2][4]=...;
    $ar[2][3]=...;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так понимаю:

```
$ar[2][3] = 4;
$ar[5][6] = 42;
$ar[2][32] = 43;
$ar[2][1] = 45;
$need = 3;
foreach($ar as $key1 => $ar2){
    foreach($ar2 as $key2 => $value){
        if($key2 == $need){
            echo $key1 . ' => ' . $value . '<br />';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе:

```
2 => 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$first_key = reset(array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
$tmp = array_keys($ar[2]);
echo $tmp[1];
```

Comment: Видимо я не так обяснил))) мне нужен сам ключ)) а не значение массива по ключу.

Comment: поправил. но в принципе (если правильно понял), то это очевидно array_values поменять на array_keys =)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($ar as $k=>$a){echo $k;break;}
```